# Find the spectrum and resolvent of the following operator in $A:l^{2}\rightarrow l^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

While studying functional analysis I started with spectral theory and while doing some exercises of spectrum in my source book, I came up with this one:

> Find the spectrum and resolvent of the following operator in $A:l^{2}\rightarrow l^{2}$ such that $Ax=(0, x_{1},x_{2},0,x_{4},x_{5},\dots, x_{3n+1},x_{3n+2},\dots)$

First I tried doing the following:

Take $x,y\in l^{2}$ and $(Ax-\lambda)x=y$, so $Ax=\lambda x$.

Now, for all $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\dots)$ we have that:
$\lambda x_1=0,$
$\lambda x_2=x_1,$
$\lambda x_3=x_2,$
$\lambda x_4=0,$
$\lambda x_5=x_4,$
$\lambda x_6=x_5,$
$\vdots$
$\lambda x_{3n+1}=0 $
$\lambda x_{3n+2}=x_{3n+1}$
$\lambda x_{3n+3}=x_{3n+2}$
From these we have we obtain that for $\lambda=0$ then $\{0\}$ is part of the spectrum, but now, how should I proceed to find the $\lambda$ which are not zero and still part of the spectrum?

---

Regarding this problem, I asked my professor for a way to find this $\lambda\neq 0$ and he told me that I should play with the powers of $A$, but I don't understand what to do with this information.
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have not done the computation, but if $A^m =0$, then there are not too many choices for eigenvalues. Namely, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $0=A^m x = \lambda^m x$. Thus, $0$ would be the only possible eigenvalue.

Comment: Initialy, I also thought the same, but when I talked with my professor and he told me there are more elements in the spectrum, and that my method was complicated, and that I should see what happens with the powers of A.

Comment: That is of course true. Have you tried to use the Neumann series to get the resolvent? If $B$ is an operator with $\Vert B \Vert<1$, then $(Id-B)^{-1} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n$. Now we can try to see whether we can do the same for $(\lambda Id -A)^{-1}=\lambda^{-1} (Id-\lambda^{-1}A)^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh I haven´t tried that, can you explain a little more, because I am not really familiarized with the Neumann series.

Comment: Well, it's essentially the geometric series, but for operators. I suggest you try to prove first that $\Vert B \Vert<1$ implies that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n$ converges and then that $$(Id-B)\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n = Id = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n\right) (Id-B).$$ In particular this gives you a convenient way of expressing the resolvent of $(Id-B)$ as a series (respectively you prove that the resolvent exists). Once you understand how this works, try to see what happens if $B^m=0$, can we get around the smallness assumption of the norm?

Comment: Thank you very much, I´ll try to do that!

Comment: You're welcome. If you manage to make it work, it would be nice if you could write it up as an answer, such that the next person could also benefit from your insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\lambda\notin \sigma(A)$ iff $A-\lambda I:\ell^2\rightarrow \ell^2$ is a bijection. In this case we call $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ the resolvent. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then we can formally write
$$(A-\lambda I)^{-1}=\lambda^{-1}(\lambda^{-1}A-I)^{-1}=-\lambda^{-1}(I-\lambda^{-1}A)^{-1}.$$

In fact, if one of the expressions exist, then so do the other. However, the RHS looks like the result of a geometric series. Hence, we might expect that we can write

$$ (I-\lambda^{-1}A)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n $$
for $\vert\lambda\vert $ sufficiently large. Indeed, this is the so-called Neumann series and one can prove that it converges if $\Vert \lambda^{-1}A \Vert<1$ (just like for the geometric series). Indeed, we have $\Vert (\lambda^{-1}A)^n \Vert \leq \Vert \lambda^{-1}A \Vert^n$ and hence we get

$$ \left\Vert \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n \right\Vert
\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Vert(\lambda^{-1}A)^n \Vert \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Vert \lambda^{-1} A \Vert^n.  $$
Thus, for $\Vert \lambda^{-1}A\Vert<1$ the series converges. In particular, for $\vert \lambda \vert > \Vert A \Vert$ the series converges. However, if the series converges absolutely, then we check that this series really gives the inverse $(I-\lambda^{-1}A)^{-1}$ as we know it for the geometric series. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
(I-\lambda^{-1}A) \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n\right)
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n - (\lambda^{-1}A) \sum_{n=0}^\infty(\lambda^{-1}A)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n
= I.
\end{align*}
Similarly one shows that
$$ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n\right)(I-\lambda^{-1}A) =I. $$
Therefore, we have
$$ (I-\lambda^{-1}A)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n $$
for $\vert \lambda \vert > \Vert A \Vert$. This means that $\lambda$ cannot be in the spectrum if $\vert \lambda \vert > \Vert A \Vert$.

Now what happens for small $\lambda$? The norm $\Vert \lambda^{-1} A \Vert$ is too large to apply the argument from before. Here we need to use another property of $A$. We note that $A^3 =0$. Thus, we get
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1}A)^n = I + (\lambda^{-1}A) + (\lambda^{-1}A)^2. $$
We can hope that this series still gives us the inverse. Indeed,
$$ (I-\lambda^{-1}A)\left(I + (\lambda^{-1}A) + (\lambda^{-1}A)^2I + (\lambda^{-1}A) + (\lambda^{-1}A)^2\right) = I - (\lambda^{-1}A)^3 =I $$
and similarly if we commute the two operators. This means that $(A-\lambda I)$ is invertible for all $\lambda \neq 0$ and hence only $\lambda=0$ can be in the spectrum. Note that we could have done this argument from the start, but it would have been unclear why we would try to do that.

We finally check that $0$ is in the spectrum. In fact it is even an eigenvalue as $A(0,0,1,0,0, \dots )=(0, \dots)$.

Comment: Thank you! So the inverse of any $A_\lambda:=A-\lambda I$ can be written as $\sum (\lambda^{-1}A)^n$? Since for $\lambda\in \rho(A)$, we always have that $|\lambda|>\|A\|$ (i.e., $r(A)\le \|A\|)$?

Comment: @Hermi Not quite. In general we do not have $\lambda \in \rho(A) \Rightarrow \vert \lambda \vert > \Vert A \Vert$ (look at a matrix to see that this does not hold).  It is true that for $\vert \lambda \vert > \Vert A \Vert$ we can write the resolvent in the fashion above. For $\vert \lambda \vert \leq \Vert A \Vert$ we had to use that $A$ is nilpotent (i.e. $A^m=0$ for some $m$).

Comment: I think we have the result that " \sigma(T)\subset \{\lambda: |\lambda|\le \|T\|"? So for any $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, then $|\lambda|\le \|T\|$. Is it equivalent as $|\lambda|>\|T\|$, then $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$ (i.e., $\lambda\in \rho(T)$)?

Comment: Of course it is true that $\vert \lambda \vert > \Vert A \Vert$ implies $\lambda \in \rho(A)$. However, in your first comment you wrote the other implication which is not true.

Comment: For example $0\in \rho(Id)$, but we do not have $0>1=\Vert Id\Vert$.